# Iterate a Flux, execute a Mono inside, use the result in the next step

Tags: project-reactor

I want to do the equivalent of something like below, where the result from the previous call is used in the next call to the same service using Project Reactor.

```
Message current;
Message next;
for each (Step step in steps)
{
    current = new Message(step, next);
    next = execute(current);
}
```

This is what I am trying to do using reactor:

1. For each "step" (in a flux)

   a. Creating a message for that step and the last result (null to start).

   b. Invoke the service using the message and get the result (mono).

   c. Set the last message to this result so it can be used in 1a.
2. Take the very last result

My shoddy attempt at this so far looks like:

```
return fromIterable(request.getPipeline())
    .map(s -> PipelineMessage.builder()
        .client(client)
        .step(s.getStep())
        .build())
    .flatMap(z -> {
        return this.pipelineService.execute(z);
    })
    .last()
    .map(m -> ok()
        .entity(m.getPayload())
        .type(m.getType())
        .build());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure of your exact requirement. But I think `reduce` function could help here.

```
Flux<String> stringFlux = Flux.fromIterable(Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c"));

stringFlux
        .reduce("empty", (next, step) -> {
            String current = message(step, next);
            return execute(current);
        })
        .map(String::toUpperCase)
        .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

Here message and execute are functions are like this.

```
String message(String step, String next){
    return "message[" + step + ":" + next + "]";
}

String execute(String current){
    return "execute(" + current + ")";
}
```

The final output would be the last executed message.

```
EXECUTE(MESSAGE[C:EXECUTE(MESSAGE[B:EXECUTE(MESSAGE[A:EMPTY])])])
```

The initial step can not be `null` here. Instead you could use an empty step object and treat it as `null`.

---

```
Flux<String> stringFlux = Flux.fromIterable(Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c"));

stringFlux
        .reduce(Flux.just("empty"), (Flux<String> next, String step) -> {
            Flux<String> current = message(step, next);
            return current.flatMap(this::execute);
        })
        .flatMapMany(a -> a)
        .subscribe(System.out::println);


Flux<String> message(String step, Flux<String> next){
    return next.map(v -> "message(" + v + ":" + step + ")");
}

Mono<String> execute(String current){
    return Mono.just("execute(" + current + ")");
}
```

Output:

```
execute(message(execute(message(execute(message(empty:a)):b)):c))
```

Comment: I was able to piecemeal my solution from yours.  Thank you.  It is still somewhat magical to me but it seems to do what I am looking for, ill try to trace through later to understand it better.